# React Native. Обнаружить, что приложение удалено

Tags: android, ios, react-native, app, delete

Приложение разрабатывается для 3 платформ: Android, Huawei, iOS.

В приложении реализованы PUSH-уведомления.
Android и iOS через Firebase (FCM), Huawei через Huawei Push Kit.

Необходимо своевременно определять, что пользователь удалил приложение на любой из платформ.

На данный момент пробовал по расписанию отправлять PUSH-уведомления, содержащие только данные, data атрибут. Вылезла проблема, для iOS. Если для Android Firebase сервер возвращает "NotRegistered", то для iOS всегда возвращается идентификатор отправки, даже через сутки после удаления приложения.

Подскажите, есть ли решения для данной задачи, работающие одинаково хорошо на всех платформах.

Answer (score 0):

В целом задача не имеет решения. Приблизительное же решение можно сделать немного наоборот. Не пуши слать, которые дойдут или нет, а вместо этого периодически из приложения стучать к себе на сервер. Если какое-то время приложение на сервер не стучало - считать его удалённым. Хотя, конечно, это может значить и что девайс выключен, нет сети, юзер явно запретил приложению запускаться etc. Для Android используйте [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), а для iOS, похоже, аналогом будет [Background Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks). Возможно, есть либы под ReactNative, которые как раз эти нативные либы оборачивают.